# React and Jest - testing a component using PropTypes.instanceOf

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have a React component using a property defined as an instance of an ES6 class with `PropTypes.instanceOf(MyClass).isRequired`.
When testing using an instance of a mock class, I always get a console error: `Warning: Failed prop type`.

I tried various techniques based on https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks and https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html , but none of them work: the type never matches what is expected (even when the class name is the same).

How would I test the component using a mock class without removing the type checking ?

Comment: so did you mock this class like `jest.mock('path-to-file')` in your test?

Comment: I tried that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was not defining the mock class at the right place: I was defining it outside of `jest.mock`, but it should be defined inside, like this:

```
jest.mock("./MyClass", () => {
  return class {
    /* mock methods here */
  }
});
```

Also, returning a function instead of a class will not work.
So simple when you know it...